# Paste without changing font

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtextedit

Whenever I paste text into a QTextEdit widget, it pastes without changing the font or color. Is there a flag I can set to prevent this? Couldn't find anything on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste text in, try holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while you paste it in.